# Amplify: Lambda@Edge for Next CloudFront + DynamoDB permissions problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, next.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am deploying a Next.js app to Amplify with the amplify-cli. I've connected my amplify app to a couple of **existing** (created with terraform) DynamoDB tables. I've managed to modify the attached amplify app's Service role adding in the `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess` permission policy (I'll restrict it down later). I would've thought this would work, but it **does not propagate down to the created `API Lambda@Edge for Next CloudFront distribution`** or `Default Lambda@Edge for Next CloudFront distribution`

I can see logs showing permission errors from these lambdas.

```
arn:aws:sts::999999999:assumed-role/rgsuvm9-psuzoeg/us-east-1.ggvvff-abc123 is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Scan on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:6666666666:table/MyTable
```

I noticed these roles that have been automatically created with generated names for `AWS Service: lambda` trusted entitees that have policies attached for **allowing access to logs and S3 only**.

[image: list of generated edge lambda roles]

Here is an example of one of the attached permission policies for these generated roles (this is before I have manually edited it to add dynamodb access permission):

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::z0kq2lk-i0l0usx/*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Manually selecting one of these and adding dynamodb read/write permissions fixes the problem and the SSR edge lambda seems to have the correct permissions to connect to the dynamodb - great, but this isn't a nice way to do it**

My question is: How to change the permissions of the SSR Lambda? It's not a feasible or a good solution for me to manually add these permissions to this role that's clearly generated.

It seems odd to me that it doesn't use the service role that's assigned in the amplify app's general settings. Could that be a problem with amplify - or have I misconfigured the service role? (my service role used uses the `AdministratorAccess-Amplify` and `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess` policies so to my mind there's no point pasting these in).

Comment: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1087 - looks like someone else has faced this issue in the past and hacked up the cloudformation to workaround.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Amplify offers a [workflow](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/function/#access-existing-aws-resource-from-lambda-function) for referencing pre-existing resources, which Functions will need to access.

Referencing DynamoDB resources and actions according to the documentation will *likely* ensure auto-generated policies contain required IAM permissions. If you are using Terraform, consider using it to deploy your Lamba resources or use it to generate ARN outputs to configure Amplify deployment context — unifying the deployment workflow will help avoid future issues with synchronizing changes to different components.